# What is $\lim_{h\to 0}\ h\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{n}\right)$?

Tags: limits

What is $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\ h\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{n}\right)$?

I am facing a similar situation my Complex Analysis textbook, and don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: $\sum n$ is divergent, hence the sum is not defined. you need to specify what meaning you're assigning to it because the traditional one won't work

Comment: @mm-aops- So is $0.(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{n})$ not defined?

Comment: Look at the limit $\lim_{h\to 0} = h \times \frac{1}{h}$ (which equals $1$). This is on the form  $0\times \infty$, but both $h$ and $\frac{1}{h}$ are finite for every $h \not= 0$. In your expression you have $h \times \infty$ for *every* $h$ which is why the limit does not make sense. An example of a limit that makes sense is for example $\lim_{h\to 0} h \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor 1/\sqrt{h}\rfloor}n$. Here everything is finite and the limit exists (=$1/2$).

Comment: A believe this question illustrates that for limits to be interchangeable, they both need to exist. Although the above does not exists, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{\left(\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\ h~n\right)}$ does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum is divergent so for every $h\ne 0$ the expression $\displaystyle h\sum_{n=0}^\infty n$ is divergent, that is has no value. So there is no such limit  $f(x)$ must be defined in some neighbourhood of $z$ to define $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to z}f(x)$.